# Can I use Cassandra as Apache Airflow backend DB

Tags: flask, cassandra, airflow

I was going through the Airflow documentation and as per [the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html)

*As Airflow was built to interact with its metadata using the great SqlAlchemy library, you should be able to use any database backend supported as a SqlAlchemy backend.*

Although Cassandra doesn't support SqlAlchemy, I see the project [Flask-CQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-CQLAlchemy/) provides and SQLAlchemy like API.

*Flask-CQLAlchemy handles connections to Cassandra clusters and provides a Flask-SQLAlchemy like interface to declare models and their columns in a Flask app Links*

I am just getting started with Airflow and trying to setup its backend Db, will Cassandra with Flas-CQLAlchemy works for Airlow metadata repo?